# Is an epimorphism of sheaves locally surjective?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, sheaf-theory

I am currently reading chapter 6.5 (Morphisms of Sheaves and Sheafification) in *Bosch: Algebraic Geometry and Commutative Algebra* and there is something in the context of epimorphisms of sheaves that confuses me.

> **Definition.** (*Bosch*) Let $\varphi \colon \mathcal{F} \rightarrow \mathcal{G}$ be a morphism of sheaves. Then $\varphi$ is called an *epimorphism*, if $\operatorname{im} \varphi = \mathcal{G}$.

In the chapter, $\operatorname{im} \varphi$ is defined as the sheafification of the presheaf
$$ \begin{align}(\operatorname{im} \varphi)_{\text{pre}} \colon \mathbf{Ouv(X)} &\longrightarrow \mathbf{Ring} \\
U &\longmapsto \operatorname{im} \varphi(U) \end{align} $$

The sheafification of a presheaf $\mathcal{H}$ is defined by a universal property and constructed via the associated presheaf $\mathcal{H}^+$, where
$$ \mathcal{H}^+(U) := \varinjlim_{\mathfrak{U} \in I_U} H^0(\mathfrak{U}, \mathcal{H}).$$

Then we get a sheafification $\mathcal{H}' = \mathcal{H}^{++}$. But in our case one can even show
$$(\operatorname{im} \varphi)_{\text{pre}}^{'} = (\operatorname{im} \varphi)_{\text{pre}}^{+}.$$

**Here is where I am struggling:**

I claimed and tried to proof the following

**Lemma.** Let $\varphi \colon \mathcal{F} \rightarrow \mathcal{G}$ be a morphism of sheaves. Then $\varphi$ is an epimorphism if and only if $\varphi$ is locally surjective (i.e. for any section $g \in \mathcal{G}(U)$ and any $x \in U$ there is an open neighbourhood $U_x \subseteq U $ of $x$ and a section $f \in \mathcal{F}(U_x)$ with $\varphi(U_x)(f) = g\vert_{U_x}$).

I did several attempts involving the mentioned direct limit and it always nearly worked out, but so far no success. Is my claimed Lemma even true? Is the definition of epimorphism a correct one? Or should it demand an isomorphism $\operatorname{im} \varphi \cong \mathcal{G}$ instead of $\operatorname{im}\varphi = \mathcal{G}$ since the sheafification of $ (\operatorname{im}\varphi)_{\text{pre}} $is only unique up to isomorphisms anyway? Should I (therefore also) alter the definition of *locally surjective*? But how? I am confused. Any help to clear things up is appreciated. :-)

N.B.: I am aware of the equivalence

> Let $\varphi \colon \mathcal{F} \rightarrow \mathcal{G}$ be a morphism of sheaves. Then $$ \varphi \text{ is locally surjective} \quad \iff \quad \varphi_x \colon \mathcal{F}_x \rightarrow \mathcal{G}_x \text{ is surjective for all } x. $$

But I would prefer not to use it.

Comment: In general, of $\mathcal{H}$ is a subpresheaf of a sheaf $\mathcal{G}$, then the map $\mathcal{H}' \to \mathcal{G}$ coming from the universal property of sheafification is injective; so $\mathcal{H}'$ has a canonical structure of subsheaf of $\mathcal{G}$.  So, it does make sense to ask whether $\mathcal{H}' = \mathcal{G}$.

Comment: Better verify that the image satisfies the usual universal property of the image. Explicit constructions should not be used when they are so complex.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Thanks for pointing out that there is an injective(!) canonical map $(\operatorname{im})_{\text{pre}}^+ \rightarrow \mathcal{G}$. That really was the fact I was missing.